# Fill in quarter-circle inside square using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I have drawn a square below, and I have a quarter circle inside the square, how do I fill in the quarter circle?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,3);
    \coordinate (D) at (0,3);
    \draw (A) -- (B);   
    \draw (B) -- (C);
    \draw (C) -- (D);
    \draw (D) -- (A);

    \draw (2, 3) arc[black, start angle=180, end angle=270, radius=1];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,0);
\coordinate (C) at (3,3);
\coordinate (D) at (0,3);
\draw (A) -- (B);   
\draw (B) -- (C);
\draw (C) -- (D);
\draw (D) -- (A);
\draw[fill=pink] (2,3) arc[start angle=180, end angle=270, radius=1] -- (3,3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Square with a quater circle pink corner]

Answer (score 3):

After following Qrrbrbirlbel's advice, previous code can be simplified to:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (3,3);
\draw[path picture={\draw[fill=red!30] 
     (path picture bounding box.north east) circle (1cm);}] (A) rectangle (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

*Original answer*

For fun a more complex solution. A complete circle on background layer but clipped by the rectangle. The circle must be on background to avoid redrawing the corner covered by the filling color.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (3,3);
\draw (A) rectangle (C);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]   
\clip (A) rectangle (C);
\draw[fill=pink] (C) circle[radius=1];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A `path picture` would save a few steps here.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I never used `path pictures` inside `paths`, always inside `nodes`. Thank you for your suggestion.